# Accessing Windows file property details such as Authors through Java?

Tags: java, windows, file, fileinfo, author

I'm trying to use Java on my Windows PC to sort through files and extract information about each one including Authors, which can be found by left clicking on a file > properties > details.

I've been able to extract everything I want except for this one piece of information using BasicFileAttributes, but I can't seem to find any way to get access to the details such as Authors through Java. I can get the owner of the file, but not the Authors

```
Path filePath = folder.toPath();
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, 
BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("Path leads to a file with information:");
System.out.println("Full file path: " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("Date Created: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("Last Date Modified: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
System.out.println("Author: " + Files.getOwner(filePath).getName());
```

That codeis what I currently have, but Owner isn't giving me the same results as Authors, which is what I need.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How is owner different from author? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm in a business setting, and owner gives me a general admin for the entire vm we run on, while author is able to be edited by the creator of the file with their name. Like owner prints "Builtin/Administrators," whereas I want "John Smith" from the properties of the file as described above

Comment: Not all files contain the **Author** property or many other different properties for that matter. All files however do contain the **basic** properties that you have already managed to acquire. Enhanced properties such as **author** or **Genre** for example are contained within the file itself as **metedata** and follow (go with) that file when it is copied, moved, or even deleted. You will need to extract that metadata from the file. Possibly look into using Windows **PowerShell** to extract this data. All MS Office files are actually Zip files. Unzip and locate the needed XML with properties